# find rows in Pandas Dataframe where column sum is 1 (or less) based on second column

Tags: python, pandas

What I'm trying to do is find all the rows where one person buys only one thing.

Snippet of csv file

```
(Totals),"Customer ID",BRAND,"Qty Sold",ITEM,"Customer Name","Invoice Date","Invoice ID"
,CUS0011031,"New Balance",1,"GYM SHORTS","CHARLES INCHARGE",02/01/2019,INV043989
,CUS0002720,"Under Armor",1,"GREY T-SHIRT","JACKIE CHAN",02/01/2019,INV043992
,CUS0002720,"Reebok",1,"BASKETBALL SHOES","JACKIE CHAN",02/01/2019,INV043992
,CUS0007681,"Puma",1,"780XRT RUNNING SHOES","WILLIE NELSON",02/01/2019,INV043994
,CUS0003262,"Converse",2,"CHUCK TAYLORS","PIERCE BROSNAN",02/01/2019,INV043995
,CUS0003262,"Reebok",1,"JORDAN SOCKS","PIERCE BROSNAN",02/01/2019,INV043995
,CUS0002402,"Converse",1,"CHUCK TAYLORS","DALE CHAMPIGNY",02/01/2019,INV043997
,CUS0002547,"Converse",1,"CHUCK TAYLORS","MATTHEW MCCONAUGHEY",02/01/2019,INV043999
,CUS0002547,"Reebok",1,"JORDAN SOCKS","MATTHEW MCCONAUGHEY",02/01/2019,INV043999
,CUS0008058,"Converse",1,"CHUCK TAYLORS","GENERAL PATON",02/01/2019,INV044000
,CUS0008058,"Reebok",1,"JORDAN SOCKS","GENERAL PATON",02/01/2019,INV044000
,CUS0003337,"Nike",1,"SWOOSH HAT","STEVEN HARPER",02/01/2019,INV043991
"Grand Totals (3896 Records)",,,2799.44,,,,
```

and the code I'm working with:

```
import pandas as pd

sales_df = pd.read_csv('little.csv', skipfooter=1, engine='python')
sales_df.drop(columns=['(Totals)'], inplace=True, axis=1)
sales_df.rename(columns={'Customer ID': 'Customer_ID',
                         'Qty Sold': 'QtySold',
                         'Customer Name': 'Customer_Name',
                         'Invoice Date': 'Invoice_Date'}, inplace=True)

single_sales_df = sales_df.groupby(['Customer_ID']).QtySold.sum()
with pd.option_context('display.max_rows', None, 'display.max_columns', None):
    print(single_sales_df)
```

which gives me the below:

```
Customer_ID
CUS0002402    1
CUS0002547    2
CUS0002720    2
CUS0003262    3
CUS0003337    1
CUS0007681    1
CUS0008058    2
CUS0011031    1
Name: QtySold, dtype: int64
```

which is close to what I want, but I'd only like the results that are 1 and I would also like the other columns in the result.  Any help would be appreciated.

Somewhat like this:

```
   Customer_ID        BRAND  QtySold                  ITEM  Customer_Name Invoice_Date Invoice ID 
0   CUS0011031  New Balance        1            GYM SHORTS   CHARLES INCHARGE   02/01/2019  INV043989
```

**TIA**

Comment: `sales_df[sales_df['Qty Sold']==1]` or `sales_df[sales_df.groupby('Customer ID').QtySold.transform('sum')==1]`?

Comment: yep, that second solution is what i was after, as some customer id/name span multiple rows.

Comment: if you want to make that a solution, i'll hit the check mark

Comment: never mind that, it's probably be a dup somewhere with `transform`. Happy coding.